# IIS appears to bypass proxy in web.config file

Tags: iis, proxy

We're using IIS 10 (Windows Server 2016) for an application that requires a connection to their external IP and port.  However when using WireShark to analyze network traffic the machine appears to be going directly to the IP and not through our local proxy.

Internal Host (IP)----->  external IP

We have configured the FW to allow access from the proxy and the application Web.Config to recognize the proxy settings but still can't connect.  It's trying to go directly to the external IP and not through the proxy first.

For this to work the call has to go from our proxy to the external IP

Internal host-->internal proxy--->external IP

I've configured the proxy settings as I know how

```
<defaultProxy>
  <!--<proxy usesystemdefault="true"/> -->
 <proxy proxyaddress="http://172.22.0.999:8080" bypassonlocal="true" /> 
</defaultProxy>


<proxy autoDetect="false" proxyaddress="http://172.22.0.999:8080" bypassonlocal="true" usesystemdefault="false" />
```

Yet it still is NOT going through the proxy.  Is there another file that could be overriding the settings in web.config?

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: That setting you used only applies to ASP.NET applications, and IIS generally speaking ignores it.

Comment: Thanks, do you know the proper way to configure IIS for a proxy?

Comment: The actual web framework you use (other than ASP.NET) should have a setting for you, but not IIS.